# Issues with second call back to ajax web method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

so I've this ajax method that help me to find the selected row from a table, and the display the information into a series of fields. The problem is that the first time the call is made works really fine. But as soon as I search for another record the data is not displayed and I get this error in the web-explorer console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Detalles' of null
```

'Detalles? being the array that json bring me back. So I think is a problem with the time of the request, any advices on this? Here is ajax method:

```
return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../../ServiciosWeb.asmx/CargarDetallesRequisicion",
        data: '{IdRequisicion:"'+ idRequisicion +'" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false
});
```

I hope someone can help me... thanks!

**UPDATE:**
This is the method that convert my info to JSon

```
Function DataSetToJSON(ds As DataSet) As String
        Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)

        For Each dt As DataTable In ds.Tables
            Dim arr(dt.Rows.Count - 1) As Object

            For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                arr(i) = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray
            Next

            dict.Add(dt.TableName, arr)
        Next

        Dim json As New JavaScriptSerializer
        Return json.Serialize(dict)
    End Function
```

I check the return of the data when is appointed to null and yes, it brings the information, that's why to me is something to do with the time. Here is where I call the `$.ajax` method:

```
 if (idRequisicion > 0) {
        console.log(idRequisicion);
        $.when(
        CargarDetalles()
        ).done(MostrarDetalles);
    }
```

This condition is placed in the `$(document).ready`

**SOLVED:**

So it came to this:

```
if (idRequisicion > 0) {

        function MostrarInformacion(fn, tiempo) {

            var dfd = $.Deferred();

            setTimeout(function () {

                dfd.resolve(fn());
            }, tiempo || 0);

            return dfd.promise();
        }
        var promise = MostrarInformacion(function () {
            $.blockUI({
                css: {
                    border: 'none',
                    padding: '0',
                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                    '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                    '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                    opacity: .5,
                    color: '#fff',
                    onBlock: $.when(CargarDetalles()).done(MostrarDetalles)
                }
            });
            setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000);

            }, 300);

    }
```

Ignore the BlocUI, that's new. In conclusion this solve my problem maybe is not the most efficient way to do it but form the moment works fine.

Comment: Try some other records....maybe the ajax request failed the second time becuase it didnt find a match.

Comment: JSON format says you ought to use parentheses:
`data: '{"IdRequisicion": "'+ idRequisicion +'" }',`

Comment: change your data line

data: '{IdRequisicion:"'+ idRequisicion +'" }', 
to
data: {IdRequisicion: idRequisicion },

but you have to provide us with more javascript code

Comment: don't write json manually , it is error prone and you already have an error in quotes. Use JSON.stringify to do it for you. Need to show more code , not clear where `$.ajax` is being returned to or where callback is for response

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a problem of your request, you are trying to access to a property of null. maybe your backend is returning nothing , you verified your response? are you getting something in your backend?  can you post something about the Response ?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.when expects deferred objects:

```
jQuery.when( deferreds ) Returns: Promise
```

> Provides a way to execute callback functions based on one or more
>   objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

You should put your ajax request inside of the $.when directly and not a function call, like this:

```
 $.when(
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../../ServiciosWeb.asmx/CargarDetallesRequisicion",
        data: '{IdRequisicion:"'+ idRequisicion +'" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false
}
        ).done(MostrarDetalles);
```

if you need the same settings, maybe you should return only the ajax settings like `$.ajax(CargarDetalles())` and not the complete request